# .net connectionManagement Not Working

Tags: .net

I have Set Following Setting, But Still My Web Service Accept Only 2 Request At a Time..

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
         <add address = "*" maxconnection = "200" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>`enter code here
```

Comment: Its probably because of servser configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help..

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="" executionTimeout="3600" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Above Cinfiguration Give Me Error As Follow:The value of the property 'maxRequestLength' cannot be parsed. The error is:  is not a valid value for Int32.

Comment: Is not a valid value for Int32 means that the value you are giving inside maxRequestLength should be of integer type i.e. the value must be between 0 and 2097151